# Eclipse import all PMD rulesets

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

Encountered in Eclipse 4.2 & 4.3. With PMD plugin installed.

At PMD > Rule Configuration, browse to select a rule-set file.

Presuming that we had cleared all existin rulesets, when ruleset file is successfully chosen, the combo box would list all the rulesets categorically. Let's say there are 300 rules, categorised into 50 rulesets.

I have to click on browse, select next ruleset fifty times to import all the rules of the file. That was a waste of time. I need to find a way to click once and import all the rules rather then clicking 50 x (browse+select+ok) = 50 x 3  = 150 clicks.

Could someone tell me how to perform a one-click import of all rules?

If such avenue does not exist, why do the PMD authors of the plugin not provide it? Would importing all rules all at once have possibility of encountering conflicts?